# How can I use a React component in other component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component right here

Scanner.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import BarcodeScannerComponent from "react-qr-barcode-scanner";

function Scanner() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState("Not Found");

  return (
    <>
      <BarcodeScannerComponent
        width={500}
        height={500}
        onUpdate={(err, result) => {
          if (result) setData(result.text);
          else setData("Not Found");
        }}
      />
      <p>{data}</p>
    </>
  );
}
export default Scanner;
```

I want to use this component inside of another Component, best would be on Button click.
But this is not possible because i am breaking the rules of Hooks in React. And for use, i have to use "data" from Scanner component and then send it to Order Component.

Comment: Hey there, it would be better to create another component which is a file called whatever you want. and then import that file wherever you want.

Comment: I already tried it.

import React from "react";
import BarcodeScannerComponent from "react-qr-barcode-scanner";

const Scanner = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState("Not Found");

  return (
    <div>
      <BarcodeScannerComponent
        width={500}
        height={500}
        onUpdate={(err, result) => {
          if (result) setData(result.text);
          else setData("Not Found");
        }}
      />
      <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Scanner;


And using this as an import instead of the component itself, Doesnt work either.

Comment: Well, this is not how you should do it, please update your question, and add the code of the component you want to render in another component, so I can tell you what to do, thanks

Comment: Edited it as you wished

Comment: Did you notice that the `web` tag says "Do not use this tag"? Please look at the tag and what it says it is about before using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, well!
so now I understand what is the problem,
first I think you have **these 2 files** in one **component**, if yes, it would be like this.

first, **import** your **Scanner.js** in the Order.js component. like this.

```
import Scanner from "./Scanner";
```

and then render it wherever you want in the order component, it would be like this.

```
 <div className='form-group'>
          <label htmlFor='palette'>Palette</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='form-control'
            id='palette'
            name='palette'
            placeholder={currentOrder.palette}
            value={currentOrder.palette}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
          <Scanner/>
        </div>
```

that's it

## Update 1

I see you have some problem with your code:

```
     <BarcodeScannerComponent
        width={500}
        height={500}
        onUpdate={(err, result) => {
          if (result) setData(result.text);
          else setData("Not Found"); // you don't need else in this position. it would be as follow.
         setData("Not Found");
        }}
      />
```

good luck:)

Comment: This doesnt work either :/ 
https://imgur.com/a/FVW4lSh

Comment: Please take a look at the updated I made in my answer, and also if it doesn't work, share here how you imported the Scanner.js, thanks

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wbMV7PJ

Comment: Ok, I made some changes in your scanner.js please take a look and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Yes it is working! Thank you so much :)

Comment: But another question, how do i get the "data" from Scanner.js and use it in Order.js

Comment: Happy it works, 

ok, you can get data from scanner.js as a parameter in Order.js  like this.
const Order = ({place here what you want}) =>.

and please mark this answer as the correct one so I can answer other questions as well. thanks

Comment: @John in your code, the comment `// you don't need else in... ` is wrong. If the else is not there and response is truthy, setData will be called twice, once with `result.text` and once with "Not found".